# What does PHPUnit Strict mode do?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am wondering about what "strict mode is in PHPUnit" ?

eg:

```
phpunit --strict
```

or in phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit strict="true"/>
```

I turned it on just to try it and my tests started failing with

```
PHP_Invoker_TimeoutException: Execution aborted after 1 second
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Short answer:**
for long running tests use an annotation to increase the allowed run time:

```
@large // 10 seconds
@medium // 5 seconds
@small // 1 second max <-- Default, so no point using
```

**Long Answer:**

Here is an updated set of info that was derived with the help of @Crozin.

In my case the error was that a test was taking too long (>1 second.) (Doctrine ORM schema drop + create can slow things down, [see this ZendCast for what I was doing](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/)). This was causing an issue (and some output) from PHP_Invoker. Strict mode doesnt allow any output.

By Reading / Reverse engineering /usr/share/php/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Test.php::getSize()  (and getGroups() on the same class) .. I figured out there are 3 undocumented annotations we can use:

```
@large  // 10 seconds
@medium // 5 seconds
@small // 1 second max run time
```

They can be specified on the class level or on the method level.
[Issue #490 on the PHPUnit github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/490) hints at issues with supplying both class level and method level so YMMV if you mix them. As crozin said, the allotted time outs are 10,5,1 seconds respectively.

A alternate solution was to increase how long an invoked function is allowed to run (on my slow computer).

```
sudo vi /usr/share/php/pear/share/pear/PHP/Invoker.php

Increase line 1 "declare(ticks = 1);" to
    "declare(ticks = 10);" // or any higher int that meets your needs
```

Here is a bunch of information about strict mode that helped me find the solution:

> PHP_Invoker 
>      A utility class for invoking callables with a timeout. This package is required to enforce test timeouts in strict mode. [[PHPUnit Install Instructions](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)]
>
> Strict Mode
>      Tests that do not assert anything are marked as incomplete
>      Test that are incomplete (or skipped) yield no code coverage [Slideshare by Sebastian Bergmann (slide 10)](http://www.slideshare.net/sebastian_bergmann/towards-more-meaningful-code-coverage)
>
> Note 
>   Please note that PHPUnit swallows all output that is emitted during the execution of a test. In strict mode, a test that emits output will fail. [Testing output section of PHPUnit Manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output)

Comment: Change allowed time for tests you van also in phpunit.xml file as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13722524/1387163

Answer (score 35):

> Please note that PHPUnit swallows all output that is emitted during the execution of a test. In strict mode, a test that emits output will fail.

That's all I could find in documentation, but I'd also checked the sources and I found that in strict mode:

1. Tests with no assertions might be marked as incomplete/failures.
2. Each test might be run with execution time limit depending on it's size and the presence of the [pcntl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) and [PHP_Invoker library](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-invoker). There are three timeouts values:

   - `timeoutForSmallTests` (default value: 1)
   - `timeoutForMediumTests` (default value: 10)
   - `timeoutForLargeTests` (default value: 60)

   The test size (small, medium or large) is determined by the `PHPUnit_Util_Test::getSize()` method:

   - Test cases descending from `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase` or `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase` are large.
   - Test cases and individual tests can also be made large or medium by adding them to the 'large' or 'medum' [groups](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group), respectively.
   - Otherwise, the test is small.

---

It's seems that strict mode does only the above three changes, but I'm not absolutely sure about that. I have never studied PHPUnit's sources before, nor used strict mode.