# PHPUnit strict mode - how to change default timeout

Tags: php, timeout, phpunit

I'd like to keep running my unit tests in strict mode so that I'm aware of any exceptionally long tests easily, but at the same time the default timeout of 1s is not enough. Can I change it for all tests? I know I can set timeout for each class (and individual tests) using `@short / @medium / @long` annotations, but is there something like that for all tests? Perhaps in phpunit.xml?

This is to avoid `PHP_Invoker_TimeoutException: Execution aborted after 1 second` that happens once in a while.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520464/what-does-phpunit-strict-mode-do

Comment: I've looked at that, but it does not answer how to change this setting globally - without editing PHPUnit source code, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You can only do it from phpunit.xml. There is no global configuration file for PHPUnit as far as I know.

Comment: So how would I change the default timeout while keeping strict mode on?

Comment: From the accepted answer, set timeoutForSmallTests to the value you want. It goes to the header where other config values (strict mode for example :P) goes.

Comment: Ah, I totally did not realise that was an option for phpunit.xml - many thanks! Feel free to post below and I'll accept / upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The option can be enabled by setting wanted times in phpunit.xml. The times are in seconds.

Example:

```
<phpunit
    strict="true"
    timeoutForSmallTests="1"
    timeoutForMediumTests="5"
    timeoutForLargeTests="10"
>
 // test suites
</phpunit>
```

Tests can be marked to be medium or large by marking actual tests functions like following

```
/**
 * @medium
 */
public function testTestThing() {
     $this->assertTrue(false);
}
```

EDIT: [modern PHPUnit versions](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-4.5.0#deprecated-settings) does not do these timeouts any more, and also changes the behaviour of strict mode generally by introducing separate flags for each thing [previously covered by strict mode](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/risky-tests.html):

```
beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="true"
beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
beStrictAboutTestSize="true"
beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
```

Unrelated warning: it also changes paths to tests in the XML config to be relative to the XML config file, as opposed to old default that paths are to be relative to current working dir.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can set them also in your setUp() method like this:

```
$this->getTestResultObject()->setTimeoutForSmallTests(1);
$this->getTestResultObject()->setTimeoutForMediumTests(5);
$this->getTestResultObject()->setTimeoutForLargeTests(10);
```